# Microsoft Excel 2013 - VBA Macro - Insert value and select next cell in same column (row underneath)

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm rather new to using Macros and I'm creating a simple worksheet that allows me and my co-workers to take notes in the field.

What I need is to have a simple click button that runs a really basic macro. I have no trouble adding the button and running a macro that adds the value I need ("N") to the active cell but I need the macro to then select the next cell in the column, in the row below, so that if I can click the button again to add the same value to the selected cell and moving to the next cell in the column.

Thanks in advance!

[image: example.png]

Comment: A long time ago I got a book about Excel Macros.  It contained excellent advice.  Use the macro recorder to write as much as your code as possible.

Comment: I have used the macro recorder and it still does not record the enter key.

Comment: I just tried it myself with Excel 2010.  I was in cell A1 and pressed the enter key.  The resulting code was "Range("A2").Select".

Comment: But that code does nothing towards what I needed. It simply keeps it reverting to cell A2. I needed the active cell to continue down the page each click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub NPlacer()
    ActiveCell.Value = "N"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```